# Сравнить версию программы с версией указанной в конфиг файле

Tags: c++

Нужно, чтобы программа сравнивала версию указанную в константе (`const std::string verconst="version=0.2"`) с версией которая хранится в конфиг файле. Сделал считывание всего содержимого из конфига, не пойму как считать определённый участок текста, чтобы сравнить его с константой.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <getopt.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream confFile;
    const char path[]="~/.config/lesson3/config.ini";
    const std::string verconst="version=0.2";
    int opt;
    std::string config, line,ver;
    bool isConfig = false;
    static struct option long_options[] = {
            {"config",   required_argument, 0,'c' },
        };

    int long_index =0;
    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "c:", long_options, &long_index )) !=-1){
        switch(opt){
        case 'c':
           isConfig = true;
           config = optarg;
           cout << "Config = " << "[ " << config << " ]" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!isConfig){
        config = path;
        cout << "Config = " << "[ " << config << " ]" << endl;
    }
    confFile.open(config);
    if(confFile.is_open()){
        while(getline(confFile, line)){
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        confFile.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Can't open file: " << config << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Возьмите любую (точнее -подходящую для вашего формата) библиотеку для разбора конфигов и используйте её. В Windows, ЕМНИП, стандартные конфиги вообще через WinAPI читаются. И получится что-то вроде:

```
if( myversion == config.get("version") ) ...
```

Comment: в принципе, судя по всему, автору не повредит и изучение токенизаторов/регулярных выражений/способов разбить строку на пары ключ/значение

Comment: Значит, `s/взять готовую/написать свою/` ;) Но посмотреть на существующие решения всё равно полезно будет.